# What does this mean/what is the ^ operator?

Tags: c++, c++-cli

Finished an online C++ course and was looking at some code, what does this mean?

```
DWORD remark(array<String^>^ args);
```

Specifically this part, I get the rest: `array<String^>^ args`

I don't have access to the rest of the code, it's compiled, but this is one of the functions I'm able to use.

It's like... converting an array pointer of a string of arrays XOR to an argument or something...

Comment: It's some silly managed pointer used by Microsoft's CLI. In this context, it's **not** the XOR operator. (Don't understand the downvote; this is difficult to search for.)

Comment: @Bathsheba ...and what exactly makes this silly?

Comment: Extending C++ in this manner is only going to cause headaches with future C++ standards. The ISO committee ain't going to give two hoots about breaking C++/cli with new features. See this for an example https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/3814789-support-c-11-concurrency-header-files-in-c-cli